# Recorrer Array dentro de otro en Vue.Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

tengo el siguiente array;

```
[ {
  "Id" : 1,
  "GameCreated" : "2020-05-16T10:57:27.26073",
  "GamePlayers" : [ {
    "Id" : 2,
    "Player" : {
      "Id" : 2,
      "Email" : "c.obrian@ctu.gov"
    }
  }, {
    "Id" : 1,
    "Player" : {
      "Id" : 1,
      "Email" : "j.bauer@ctu.gov"
    }
  } ]
},
```

Estoy intentando recorrerlo con Vue.Js con un v-for, todo bien hasta la primera vuelta, me devuelve "Id", y "GameCreated", no me devuelve "GamePlayers" por que tiene adentro otro array, no encuentro la forma de hacer que itere dentro de este ultimo y me devuelva las correspondientes keys, hasta ahora se ve asi en pantalla;

```
1 2020-05-16T10:57:27.26073
2 2020-05-16T11:57:27.26073
3 2020-05-16T12:57:27.26073
```

y necesito tener el ID y player que estan adentro de gameplayers tambien,

desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor considera editar y agregar lo que lleves aunque este incompleto o tenga errores, de ese modo te podemos dar soluciones